# PHP code to encode DB data in JSON not working

Tags: php, json

I'm currently stuck with some PHP code. I want to access a table in my database and retrieve the data in a JSON format. Therefore, I tried the following code :

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("......","username","pwd","DBName");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

if ($result = mysql_query($con, $sql))
{

    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();    

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

However, it's getting me an empty page. It worked once but only with a special number of row in the table, so not very efficient as you might guess.

Does anybody have an idea why i'm getting those weird results?

**EDIT 1 :**

I Just tried to add this to my code :

```
echo json_encode($resultArray);
echo json_last_error();
```

And it's returning me 5. It seems to be an error from the data encoding in my table. Therefore I added that code :

```
$tempArray = array_map('utf8_encode', $row)
array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
```

And I got the following output : [null,null,null]0 (The zero comes from the echo json_last_error();)

So here I am, can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: You can't mix SQL API's - change `mysql_query()` to `mysqli_query()` and swap the order of its arguments around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution ! That was indeed an encoding problem, the json_encode() function accepts only strings encoded in utf8. I changed the interclassement of my table to utf8_general_ci and I modified my code as follows :

```
<?php
//Create Database connection

$db = mysql_connect(".....","username","pwd");

if (!$db) {

    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());

}


//Select the Database

mysql_select_db("DBName",$db);



//Replace * in the query with the column names.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users", $db); 


//Create an array

$json_response = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['name'] = utf8_encode($row['name']);
    $row_array['lastName'] = utf8_encode($row['lastName']);

    //push the values in the array

    array_push($json_response,$row_array);

}

echo json_encode($json_response);
//Close the database connection

fclose($db);

?>
```

And I got the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by changing `if ($result = mysql_query($con, $sql))` to `if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))` because they are different database extensions

Another thing would be to change `while($row = $result->fetch_object())` to `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {` (Procedural style vs. Object oriented style)

If you still see blank screen, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script, and you'll be able to know exactly where the bug is

Comment: Thank's Alon and Robbie for the quick answer ! I changed it to be like :
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) but it didn't worked, even when I swapped the order of the arguments !

Comment: @MJ23 - Added another suggestion to this answer

Comment: The order of `mysqli_query`'s arguments is opposite to `mysql_query`

Comment: @RobbieAverill - From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php): `mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

Comment: Nice @Alon - I was looking at the OOP line with query first.

Comment: @Alon
I just added error_reporting(E_ALL); but I still have blank screen, should it return something even if there isn't any bug ?

Comment: @MJ23 Unfortunately i'm out of ideas, the last one I can recommend is to try and add `else statement` to your `if`: `if ($result = $query) { ... } else { echo 'error. description: ' . mysqli_error($con); }`

Comment: @Alon -
I added the else part and I'm not getting any result.. I tried to just add a simple echo "test"; to see if I still have a blank page but it appears so I'm lost too ! But thank's for you time, that was appreciated :)

Comment: I tried your code and after I changed the 1 error, mysql_ to mysli_ it ran fine.  I have updated the code and posted a working version.  Check out my answer below.  Oh, a blank screen normally means a syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("......","username","pwd","DBName") 
       or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("Failed to execute query")
if ($result = $query)
{
    $resultArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        array_push($resultArray, $row);
    }
    $result->close()

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's not working either... In fact I already tried different codes that should have the same effect but I get the same blank screen every time !

Comment: Do you have display_errors on and error_reporting set to E_ALL (0). Try to post your phpinfo, so we know whats your server configuration

Comment: I added a error_reporting(E_ALL); in my script but I didn't get any output... Which things should I go through in my phpinfo ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, try it out:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("......","username","pwd","DBName");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**EDIT 1:**

As a test replace this code:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_object())
 {
  $resultArray[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

with this code:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
  print_r($row);
 }
```

What output do you get?

Comment: Hi @CharlesEF !
I tested your code and I'm still getting this blank page... The problem seems to come from the DB ? I double checked the name of the table and the name of the DB, even if an error would have occur if it was the problem..

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?  The code runs fine on my IIS (Windows) system.

Comment: Well I put the code you gave above and got the following output : 

Array ( [id] => 1 [firstName] => Jean [lastName] => Pierre [email] => jean-pierre@gmail.com [mdp] => jp [photo] => ����J,,��2��C  %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(��C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((��,,"�[date] => 2015-08-27 09:49:31 )

For photo it was a long blob so I cut it short

Comment: This means the connection to the database works and data is being returned.  That means the problem must be with the json_encode command.  That command requires PHP version 5.2.0 or higher.  What PHP version do you have installed?  Also, it appears that your table contains some blob columns.  Is this correct?

Comment: My version of PHP is 5.5.24 and with php -m I saw that I got json and mysqli that are well installed ! And indeed, I've got a blob in one of my columns, I precised it in the last comment at the end :)

Comment: I know BLOB columns need to be base64 encoded before they are converted to json.  But that in itself should not stop json_encode from working.  It would just return NULL for that column.  I must admit that I'm out of ideas at the moment.  I'll post again if I think of anything else.